# How do the current input and the output of the previous time step get combined in an LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, long-short-term-memory, architecture

I am currently looking into LSTMs. I found [this nice blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), which is already very helpful, but still, there are things I don't understand, mostly because of the collapsed layers.

- The input $X_t$, and the output of the previous time step $H_{t-1}$, how do they get combined? Multiplied, added or what?
- The input weights and the weights of the input of the previous time step, those are just the weights of the connections between the time-steps/units, right?

Comment: All i would like to say head over to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEbBIpP4c9E&index=10&list=PLZnyIsit9AM7yeTZuBmezKNc6hFHUPImh  by Andrew Ng you will understand everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $X_t$ and $H_{t-1}$ are concatenated. The blog you cited explained its notation "*Lines merging denote concatenation*". For example, if $X_t=[1,2,3]$ and $H_{t-1}=[4,5,6,7]$, then their concatenation is $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]$

(2) When you say "*input weights*" or "*weights of the input of the previous time step*", are you referring to the $W_i$ in your cited blog? If so they are not *the weights of the connections between the time-steps/units*. They are part of the input gate only. The *connections between the time-steps/units* do not have weights applied to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But: If on every time step, more elements are appended, doesn't the vector get huge after many time steps? I mean, there is the forget, ignore and update gate, but as far as I know, they only set the values they want to block to zero, they don't erase the value from the vector.

Comment: So each gate is essentially a small NN, just collapsed down into one unit using matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Ben In each step $X_t$ and $H_{t-1}$ is fixed size, so it won't become longer and longer. Note that in each cell, the concatenation of $H_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ are not directly connected to $H_{t}$, but they go through a $\sigma$ which "collapse down" the size. And yes, here $\sigma$ is small NN.